# Undefined reference to constructor when linking CompactNSearch library with Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, undefined

I want to use a library called [CompactNSearch](https://github.com/InteractiveComputerGraphics/CompactNSearch) in my project but the compilation throws an error which i have not been able to fix for hours.

#### Setup for MWE

**Directory**, clone the library with `git clone https://github.com/InteractiveComputerGraphics/CompactNSearch.git`:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── CompactNSearch 
...
└── main.cpp
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "CompactNSearch.h"
using namespace CompactNSearch;

int main()
{
    float r = 0;
    NeighborhoodSearch nsearch(r);
}
```

**CMakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(MyProject VERSION 1.0
                  LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(
    MyProject main.cpp
)

add_subdirectory(CompactNSearch)
target_link_libraries(MyProject CompactNSearch)
```

#### What i'm doing

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

#### What happens during make

```
[ 16%] Building CXX object CompactNSearch/CMakeFiles/CompactNSearch.dir/src/CompactNSearch.cpp.o
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libCompactNSearch.a
[ 33%] Built target CompactNSearch
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable MyProject
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `CompactNSearch::NeighborhoodSearch::NeighborhoodSearch(float, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/build.make:100: MyProject] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:117: CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

#### What i've tried so far

Basically any variant of linking the library with cmake that i could find - i've also tried building it as static or shared in its folder and linking that with the same result. I added a `#error This should be shown` in the constructor definition and it definitely gets compiled.

I would be very grateful for any pointers (hah) that help me - not just for this project but also to generally understand CMake better.

## SOLUTION:

Turns out the library used a compile flag to decide if `float` or `double` should be used and the default did not match my usage. So i added `set(USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION OFF)` in `CMakeList.txt` before the subdirectory is added and now everything is just peachy. Thanks everyone and hopefully this can help others, even if the problem was very specific to the library i want to use :)

---

Comment: Run `nm -C <file> | grep NeighborhoodSearch` where file is the library name

Comment: @HenriqueBucher thanks for the recommendation, did not know that tool! I pasted the output here: https://pastebin.com/N8vNfeFh
Seems to me that everything is in order. The function as a signature (float, bool) but the bool has a default value and it doesn't change a thing if i also pass a bool.

Comment: Run make with `make VERBOSE=1` and paste the command line here

Comment: The only 2 lines containing constructors in the code are 2 lines  containing `0000000000000080 T CompactNSearch::NeighborhoodSearch::NeighborhoodSearch(double, bool)`. Your code expects `NeighborhoodSearch(float, bool)` though. A look at the relevant header shows a conditionally defined type alias `Real` being used as first constructor parameter. Probably relevant compile definition wasn't added via via `target_compile_definitions(CompactNSearch PUBLIC USE_DOUBLE)` but with private visibility instead.

Comment: https://github.com/InteractiveComputerGraphics/CompactNSearch/blob/0865da3aeeb25e09b0bed4185b6f2ffb3e557909/include/Config.h#L5

Comment: Thanks Fabian, i guess after dealing with other compile errors for half the day with the larger project i did not not see this (in hindsight obvious) mismatch. It works now, i'll amend my original post. You saved me a lot of further headaches :)